# Adding jQuery vertical scrollbar to dynamic content

Tags: jquery, rss, vertical-scrolling

I'm developing a website and I want the main div to be a fixed height with a jquery vertical scrollbar for content that overflows that area.  For this, I'm using the plugin [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com).

However, I want to load this content dynamically from an RSS feed, using the plugin zRSSFeed (I'm a new user so I can't post 2 links!).

In order to do this I need to call the rssfeed function like this:

$("#feed").rssfeed(....feed url and options);

I then want to apply jScrollPane to a div that is dynamically created by calling the rssfeed function.  However each time I try to find the jQuery element, it does not yet exist.

As far as I know rssfeed does not include a callback function that I could use, and I have tried to function chain jScrollPane after calling rssfeed, but that did not work either.

Any suggestions??

Comment: I would recommend firefox with the firebug plugin if you don't already have it. It allows debugging of javascript.

Comment: Can you post some sample code of what you've tried?

Comment: This is what I was trying to do, and I was using Firebug.  I also tried to add the .children() function to the chain in order to find the inner div that was created by rssfeed, but to no avail

$("#feed").rssfeed('http://news.search.yahoo.com/news/rss?p=query&ei=UTF-8&fl=0&x=wrt', {
   limit: 5
  }).jScrollPane();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have to agree with David that it leaves a lot to wish for, but alternatively, you could just implement a callback handler yourself to the class:

In the same place as David suggested, right after the `$(e).html(html);` add the following:

`if(options.complete!=null) { options.complete();` }

Then, in your html:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#feed').rssfeed('http://myrssfeedurl', {
    limit: 5,
    complete: function() { $("#feed div").jScrollPane(); }
  });
});
```

Comment: devrooms, this is exactly what I would want to do.  I don't have time right now but I will tinker with the plugin itself to see if I can add the callback functionality.

Comment: That works too, but why check for `null`? I would do `if (typeof options.complete == 'function') { options.complete.call(e); }`

Answer (score 2):

I had a quick look at the zRSSFeed plugin and the code leaves a lot to wish for... however, you might be able to add your own trigger in the end of the _callback function, just after the `$(e).html(html);` at the very end of the script. Try adding:

```
$(e).trigger('rss');
```

And then in your main program you can listen for the rss event on the element, like:

```
$('#feed').bind('rss', function() {
    // the html should now be injected
}).rssfeed( '/stuff.xml' );
```

It's not pretty but might be a quick-fix if that's what you need here.

Comment: yea, the plugin isn't fully featured